# Using Python Subprocess to send command lines to command prompt [Error 2: The system cannot find the file specified]

Tags: python, command-prompt, popen

I'm trying to send a command line to command prompt (terminal) and read the output but I keep receiving the error:

```
self get_version(self) 
File <folder path of my script>, line 39, in get_version
stdout = subprocess.PIPE
File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 958, in _execute_child
startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Here's my code:

```
import subprocess

def get_version(self)
    command = "wmic datafile where name='c:\\Drivers\\current_version\\GenericDriverSetup.exe' get version"
    proc = subprocess.Popen([command], 
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

    stdout_value = proc.communicate()[0]
    print '\tstdout:', repr(stdout_value)
```

Can someone tell me what's wrong with this? Thanks so much

Comment: What if you do `proc = subprocess.Popen(command.split(" "), ...`?

Comment: Same error. I am only sending one string of command though.